# Windows 8 navigation, passing an URI as parameter

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I just started developing for windows 8, and I'm having some difficult in passing parameters in navigation between pages.

What I am trying to do is: I have two pages (page1 and page2) In page1, there's a menu with a button. When I click in this button, the click event should pass as a parameter an possible URI or path, that will set the source of a image in page2.

this is the code in page1:

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SplitPage), "ms-appx:/Imgs/1.png");
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SplitPage), new Uri("ms-appx:/Imgs/1.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

and page2, for receiving the Uri:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var imgSource = e.Parameter as ImageSource;
    this.imgParaPintar.Source = imgSource;
}
```

I'm noticing that `imgSource` is receiving nothing, it keeps as null.

So, any clues on what I'm doing wrong or what I am missing?

Comment: You're passing `Uri` and then casting it to `ImageSource`. `ImageSource` is not an `Uri`, why would you think that would work?

Comment: Does that `Image` class have a `UriSource` parameter?

Comment: @svick, i gave the two options i was working on, as you can see on the commented line. Both does not work.

Comment: Yes, neither `string` nor `Uri` is an `ImageSource`, so you can't cast to it. That's why your code doesn't work. How do you think it would? Magic?

Comment: The "as" operator is setting your object to null. You need to use "As Uri" (or better yet something like the "Untested" answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need code like this (untested):

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     this.imgParaPintar.Source = new BitmapImage((Uri)e.Parameter);
}
```

You might need to add `using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;` to your file, if you don't have it there already.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting, as stated in the comments here:

http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/metro/csharpvb.aspx?ID=4b847d71-9cd5-4457-add9-f68e457b23ff

That you can only pass primitive types as navigation parameters.